# Find $A^x$ where A is a $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I need to calculate $A^x$ where

$A=\pmatrix{4&-3\\3&-2}$

First of all,  $A^x = e^{x\ln A}$, so I get that

$\ln A = \pmatrix{2&0\\-1&1}$

Then I use that

$f(A)= T^{-1}f(J)T$

Here $J$ is the Jordan Canonical form. I got that

$J=\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}$

and

$T=\pmatrix{3&1\\2&0}$, $T^{-1}=\pmatrix{0&\frac{1}{2}\\1&\frac{-3}{2}}$

What should I do next? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You perhaps mean $A^x=e^{x\ln A}$?

Comment: Also, what the f is $f$?

Comment: Sure, I miss the x. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here $f=ln(A)$.

Comment: It's not clear to me how $\ln A$ can be lower-triangular, since if $B$ is lower-triangular, then so is $B^2,B^3,\dots$, so $e^B$ is lower-triangular.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain it more detailed, please?

Comment: Be specific and I might be able to answer. I meant what I wrote. Which part did you not understand? Help me help you.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but why didn't you accept my answer since it solves your question? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is this one
\begin{equation}
A^x=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
3x+1 & -3x\\
3x & -3x+1\\
\end{array}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
Now I have to exit, but as soon as I'm back I will explain it if needed...

**Edit>>:**
There are many ways to reach the same answer. The more plain one is that:
\begin{equation}
A^x=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
ax+b & cx+d\\
ex+f & gx+h\\
\end{array}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
since $A^0=I$ we have $d,f=0$ and $b,h=1$, and since $A^1=A$ we have $c=-3$ and $e=3$.
Then imposing
$$
a+b=4, g+h=-2, 
$$
we obtain $a=3$ and $g=-3$.

So for example
\begin{equation}
A^{10}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
31 & -30\\
30 & -29\\
\end{array}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: It will be nice to see explanations for this result.

Comment: I edited so now should be much clear

Comment: Sorry to bother you but why didn't you accept my answer since it solves your question?

Answer (score -1):

Hint: using the Mercator series  $$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}3 + \ldots$$

You can write $$\ln(J)=\ln(I+X) = X$$ where $X=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ so $X^2$ and higher terms are zero.